# Strange Sin[x] graph in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I randomly plotted a Sin[x] function in Mathematica 7 and this is what it shows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hizGw.png]

Note the visible defect at approximately `x = -100`.

Here is a zoom of the defect part, clearly showing that Mathematica for some reason uses a much lower resolution between the points there:

[image: mesh]

Anybody know why this happens and why only at `x = -100`?

Note: same happens in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%20from%20-42pi%20to%2042pi), by the way.

Comment: It looks like simple aliasing to me. Do you really believe that Mathematica would have a bug in something as fundamental this this?

Comment: No, that's why I was so surprised. If it was aliasing, wouldn't it however have a tendency to appear more if the interval got larger? If I change the xmin, xmax to be -60 Pi / 60 Pi, for example, it goes away.

Comment: @houbysoft I don't have Mathematica, an in fact know nothing about it, but I suggest you try varying values of the PlotPoints option

Comment: @David Heffernan : the defect only appears for PlotPoints -> 50. Strangely, it works fine for both PlotPoints -> 49 and PlotPoints -> 51.

Comment: @houbysoft & @David Heffernan. It also occurs at about x = -25 with {x, -42 \\[Pi], 41 \\[Pi]}, but (as suggested by David Heffernan), if I include PlotPoints greater than 50 the problem goes away (in both cases; Mathematica 7). Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 \\[Pi], 41 \\[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 51]

Comment: @David Heffernan: "Do you really believe that Mathematica would have a bug in something as fundamental this this?". Yes, I do.

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation is rude.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Short answer: default plotting accuracy is not sufficient for that function, so increase it as follows

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Long answer: `Plot` works by evaluating the function at a finite set of points, and connecting those points by straight lines. You can see the points used by `Plot` using the following command

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None, 
 MeshStyle -> Black]
```

> [image: plot]

You can see that for your function, the points where the function was evaluated "missed the peak" and introduced a large approximation error.  The algorithm used to pick locations of points is very simple and this situation might happen when two peaks are spaced more closely together than PlotRange/PlotPoints.

`Plot` starts with 50 equally spaced points and then inserts extra points in up to  `MaxRecursion` stages. You can see how this "hole" appears if you plot the region for various settings of `MaxRecursion`.

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotStyle -> LightGray];
Table[plot2 = 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> k]; 
  Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> {{-110, -90}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotLabel -> ("MaxRecursion " <> ToString[k])], {k, 0, 
   5}] // GraphicsColumn
```

> [image: plot]

According to Stan Wagon's Mathematica book, `Plot` decides whether to add an extra point halfway between two consecutive points if the angle between two new line segments would be more than 5 degrees. In this case, plot got unlucky with initial point positioning and subdivision does not meet that criterion. You can see that inserting a single evaluation point in the center of the hole will produce almost identically looking plot.

The way to increase the angle used to decide when to subdivide by using `Refinement` option (I got it from the book, but it doesn't seem to be documented in product)

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotStyle -> LightGray];
Show[plot1, 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -42 Pi, 42 Pi}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
   Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> 4 \[Degree]}}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-110, -90}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Here you can see that increasing it by 1 degree from default 5 fixes the hole.

[image: plot]

Comment: Ah, the Update part of your answer is exactly what I've been looking for (I knew the rest, having implemented a graphing calculator that did this myself, but I haven't included a mechanism similar to the MaxRecursion, which explains the imprecision).