# Is there a way to force ContourPlot re-check all the points on the each stage of it's recursion algorithm?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572183/strange-sinx-graph-in-mathematica/4572266#4572266) excellent analysis of the `Plot` algorithm by Yaroslav Bulatov, I now understand the reason why `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot` fail to draw smoothly functions with breaks and discontinuities.

For example, in the following case ContourPlot fails to draw contour x^2 + y^2 = 1 at all:

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x^2 + y^2 - 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Contours -> {0}]
```

It is because the algorithm does not go deeply into the region near x^2 + y^2 = 1. It "drops" this region on an initial stage and does not try to investigate it further. Increasing `MaxRecursion` does nothing in this sense. And even undocumented option `Method -> {Refinement -> {ControlValue -> .01 \[Degree]}}` does not help (but makes `Plot3D` a little bit smoother).

The above function is just a simple example. In real life I'm working with very complicated implicit functions that cannot be solved analytically.

Is there a way to get `ContourPlot` to go deeply into such regions near breaks and discontinuities?

Comment: Well, I got adaptive Plot specifics from Stan Wagon's book, but it doesn't say much about adaptive 3D plotting. Your particular example seems special because the function never crosses 0 value, it just "touches" it, my guess that's the reason ContourPlot can't find it

Comment: Strongly related: "[Problem with ContourPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23363/280)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**These are the standard Plots .**

[image]

[image]

**And the Contour at 10^-20**

[image]

They are pretty clear for me.

Do you expect something more accurate?

**Edit**

If you want to use the Contours->{0} Option, you may use:

[image]

Comment: The first `Plot3D` has jaggies on the bottom (I mean the plane `z=0`). That is non-smooth indeed. Thank you for pointing out a way to use `Contours->{.001}`. That is useful but `Mesh->All` is not suitable for my purposes. I need a smooth line without mesh.

Comment: It is the best to combine all of your suggestions with `"ControlValue"`: `ContourPlot[Abs[x^2 + y^2 - 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"CellDecomposition" -> "Quad", 
     "ControlValue" -> .01}}, Contours -> {.0001}, 
 ContourShading -> False]`. The only bad thing is that it requires a hudge number of evaluations of the objective function. In my case that is extremely slow...